# MessageBoxResult button Cancel close application

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

When the window is closing I'm calling a method `TryClose` to show a dialog. But when I click on `Cancel` the application close. Any idea just to "hide" dialog and don't do anything else?

```
public void TryClose()
{
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes?", appName, MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning);

    switch (result)
    {
        case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
            SaveAs();
            break;
        case MessageBoxResult.No:
            this.Close();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
public bool TryClose()
{
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes?", appName, MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning);

   switch (result)
   {
       case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
           SaveAs();
           return false;
       case MessageBoxResult.No:
           this.Close();
           return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

And in your closing event handler, put this:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = TryClose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   TryClose(e);
}
```

And then:

```
switch (result)
{
    case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
        SaveAs();
        break;
    case MessageBoxResult.No:
        this.Close();
        break;
    default:
        e.Cancel=true;
        break;
}
```